# Реальное разрешение окна браузера для верстки мобильной версии сайта

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, разрешение

Для верстки мобильной версии сайта использую браузерную эмуляцию мобильных устройств.
Там есть разные устройства с указанным разрешением:

- iPhone 4 с разрешением экрана 320х480px;
- iPhone SE с разрешением 375х667px;
- iPhone XR с разрешением 414х896px;
- и др.

Я так понимаю, указано разрешение всего экрана, а не окна браузера (вся высота минус верхняя полоса со временем и другими данными, и минус адресная строка браузера).

Как узнать высоту только окна браузера, в котором расположен сайт?

Мне нужно сверстать страницу, которая будет целиком помещаться в окно браузера по вертикали.